# PHP retorna um arquivo MP3

Tags: php

Eu tenho um pequeno aplicativo de música onde os arquivos são carregados a partir de uma URL como "http://www.mymusicapp.com/get_song.php?name=SOME_MUSIC".

Localmente o aplicativo funciona muito bem.

Mas, quando eu o coloco no servidor o meu aplicativo gera um erro no console do navegador.

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was
>   made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.

Meu código PHP:

```
 $song_name = $_GET['name'];
 $song_file = "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/assets/musics/{$song_name}.mp3";

 if( file_exists( $song_file ) )
 {
    header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3");
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($song_file));
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$song_name.'.mp3"');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");      
    header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');        
    readfile( $song_file );
  }
```

Comment: Seu código não está nada seguro Bruno, é possível um ataque de [code injection](http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Injection-Attacks.html) muito facilmente. `http://www.mymusicapp.com/get_song.php?name=" echo "code injection é muito massa!"; $var = "`

Comment: Obrigado pela observação gmsantos! Mas eu gostaria de fazer ele pegar antes de tudo. Tu saberia como?

Comment: O problema não é do PHP, o PHP não envia erros para a consola do navegador (pelo menos de forma nativa), muito menos erros dessa natureza. O teu problema está no código de JavaScript o qual está responsável por lidar e reproduzir o MP3. A tua pergunta na sua forma actual não é possível ser respondida com exactidão. De qualquer forma, parece-me que estás a usar o objecto antes do mesmo ter sido carregado...

Answer (score 1):

Bom, temos dois pontos, o primeiro é, se você você consegue acessar o arquivo direto do link que você está fazendo a requisição, depois, se você conseguir reproduzir, e se você estiver chamando seu arquivo por um js, verificar o que está havendo com seu ajax, ou ainda com seu frame, que você está alterando. Como desconheço seu ambiente, desconfio que o problema esteja na configuração do seu servidor ou seu .htacess, onde o seu header pode estar sendo ignorado.

Comment: Consigo sim acessá-los diretamente... percebi que na minha requisição AJAX ele só carrega 2.1 MB das músicas...